# Wake up a phone via Camera Button

Tags: android

I want to wake up my phone via camera button, b/c my power button too small.

I found some code to get Camera Button Event here:

```
public class CameraReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        // Wake up phone
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "TAG");
        wakeLock.acquire();

    }
}
```

}

Do am i in wrong way ?

Comment: If your phone is asleep, is your app running?

Comment: yes, my app is always running

Answer (score 0):

use [abortBroadcast()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#abortBroadcast%28%29) method in your `onReceive()` method.

in the manifest add

```
<receiver android:name=".CameraReceiver" >
    <intent-filter android:priority="10000">         
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>            
</receiver>
```

You will see the details in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6543792/931982)

Comment: I just want my application work in my phone in sleep mod. But with my code above a phone do not wake up, is that code wrong ?

Comment: have you declare the broadcastreceiver in manifest or in code?